# What is the best jQuery Chart framework to build stacked multiple y-axis charts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, mschart, kendo-dataviz

I am struggling to find a good jquery chart framework that supports stacked multiple y-axis so that multiple charts can be plot in a graph .I am looking at something similar to http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/stacked_charts/ or the complex graph in http://www.goldensoftware.com/Newsletter/issue52g using jQuery charting frameworks.

I have looked at the Highcharts ,Kendo Charts but could not find any options that would provide stacked y-axis on single x-axis

Comment: Have you seen [this Highstock demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume)? It works exactly the same way in Highcharts.

Comment: Highcharts will allow multiple y axes arranged vertically without a problem.  of course, worse case, which ever package you use, you could just create 3 charts and hide the x axis of 2 of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of such a chart in `Highcharts`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LHZ3E/5/

It as an Individuals and Moving Range control chart. The two sections are separate y axes, with a shared x axis in a single plot.

I would highly recommend Highcharts for this and nearly any other charting use.

Comment: Thanks jlbriggs!! Can i have more than 2 y axes,i am getting errors when i add another y axes to the existing chart

Comment: There are a total of 4 y axes on my example, with each section having an axis on both the left and the right of the chart.  Can you post an example?